# Baire space but not locally compact

Tags: general-topology, baire-category

I need an example  that is a Baire space but not locally compact. I think,
$\mathbb{R}^ \mathbb{R}$ is such an example.

$\mathbb{R}^ \mathbb{R}$ is not locally compact. But I could not proof that it is a Baire space. could you give me any hint?  where can I find the proof?

thanks

Comment: The irrationals are a Baire space. $\Bbb N^{\aleph_0}$ also. (In fact, these two spaces are homeomorphic.)

Comment: Or more generally, remove a meagre subset from a Baire space and you have a Baire space.

Answer (score 1):

Any infinite-dimensional Banach space.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by $R^R$? I haven't seen this notation. As to an example, think of a manifold and apply the Baire Category Theorem.

Comment: uncountable product of the set of real numbers is denoted by $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}^{\omega_{1}}$.

Comment: @user125176: Those are (possibly) two *very* different things. Given sets $A,B$ we typically denote the set of functions $A\to B$ by $B^A.$